# Manage Handlers in Android?

Tags: android

After Receiving the udp data I have send that byte array to the handlers for ui update. After certain period my application got crashed because of out of memory exception. android.os.messagequeue occupies 6MB of heap memory size.How to solve this issue?

Note:
I am sending byte array to update the receiving video frames and audio data

Answer (score -1):

Don't pass byte arrays to the handlers for ui update.
First decode your byte array to the String then pass it to the handlers for UI update.
this will definitely  resolve your issue.

Comment: When we pass byte array directly to handlers then it is stored in q of handlers.
And we pass after converting it to strings then only references are stored in q of handlers hence it reduces the memory consumption.